# Negative lookbehind + Non capturing group

Tags: python, regex, hyperlink, telegram, regex-group

`(?<!")https:\/\/t.me\/(c)?\/?([\+a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/?([0-9]*)?`

I want to find all telegram links without quotation marks (") but I don't want the leading negative lookbehind to be a group, how can I do this? I tried the following but it didn't work.

This code works but i want the initial negative lookbehind not to create group.

**My steps:**

- `(?:(?<!"))` not worked,
- `(?<!(?:"))` not worked either

**Examples:**

- `https://t.me/+AjFb2c8u85UfYrY0` -> True (1 group -> +AjFb2c8u85UfYrY0) (not two groups)
- `"https://t.me/+AjFb2c8u85UfYrY0` -> False

Comment: A lookbehind is not considered a group.

Comment: Why not use a single capture group? `(?<!")https://t\.me\/(?:c/)?([+a-zA-Z0-9]+)` https://regex101.com/r/T37UIr/1 Note that the optional parts at the end of the pattern outside of the group can be omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```js
const regex = /(?<!")https:\/\/t.me\/(c)?\/?([\+a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/?([0-9]*)?/
const text = 'https://t.me/+AjFb2c8u85UfYrY0'
const [fullMatch, ...groups] = text.match(regex);
console.log(groups);
```

Returns `[undefined, "+AjFb2c8u85UfYrY0", undefined]`

So you might think the first `undefined` is because of your negative lookbehind, but it's not! The first `undefined` is the result of the `(c)?` capturing group.

So if you capture groups on a url with the `/c/` pattern, here is what you'll get:

```js
const regex = /(?<!")https:\/\/t.me\/(c)?\/?([\+a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/?([0-9]*)?/
const text = 'https://t.me/c/+AjFb2c8u85UfYrY0'
const [fullMatch, ...groups] = text.match(regex);
console.log(groups);
```

So there is nothing you need to do for the initial negative lookbehind not to create group. It is already working.